# Selecting City from Customer ID in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Customer have ordered from different cities. Thus we have multiple cities against same customer_id. I want to display that city against customer id which has occurred maximum number of times , in case where customer has ordered same number of orders from multiple cities that city should be selected from where he has placed last order. I have tried something like

```
SELECT customer_id,delivery_city,COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_city)
FROM analytics.f_order
GROUP BY customer_id,delivery_city
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_city) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT customer_id, 
           delivery_city, 
           COUNT(delivery_city) as city_count, 
           MAX(order_date) as last_order
    FROM analytics.f_order
    GROUP BY customer_id, delivery_city
), ranking as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by customer_id
                                 order by city_count DESC, last_order DESC) as rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM ranking 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id,
       delivery_city,
       amount
from
(
select t.*,
       rank() over (partition by customer_id order by amount asc) as rank
from(
SELECT customer_id,
       delivery_city,
       COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_city) as amount
FROM analytics.f_order
GROUP BY customer_id,delivery_city
) t
)
where rank = 1
```

Comment: do you mean `partition by customer_id order by amount`